# Trying to install Microsoft integration run time on windows 2010

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Trying to install Microsoft integration run time on windows 2010  but getting an error

> service integration runtime service (DIAHostService )failed to start .verify that you have sufficient privilege to start the system services

Comment: There is no Windows 2010, Do you mean 2016?

Comment: I am trying to install on windows 10 os

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** You should have an entry in “log on as service” that grants the rights to the default service account.

For more details, refer [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/23145) issue which addressing similar issue.

Hope this helps.